# react native mapbox dynamically added PointAnnotations are misplaced

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I currently developing a react native app ( version 0.55.2) and mapbox/react-native (version 6.1.2-beta2)
I have a situation where some annotations are shown initially on map render, then further annotations are loaded when the user's zooms.
The first annotations are displayed at the right place.

However, when new annotations are added, there are all stuck at the top left corner.

Following their documentation, https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/MapView.md, I tried to call the function when the map is loaded or rendered. I even tried a setTimeout. The annotations always appears at the topleft map.

Any ideas how should I approach this?
THanks!

```
class map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getMapVisibleBounds = getMapVisibleBounds.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      ...INIT_MAP_STATE
    };
  }
  //compo lifecyle
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {


    if (this.state.userPosition.longitude !== prevState.userPosition.longitude) {
      this.setBounds();//first annotations. works fine
    }
    if (this.state.zoomLevel !== prevState.zoomLevel) {
     this.setBounds(); //update annotations. doesn't work
    }


  }


render()=>{
const { quest, checkpoint } = this.props;
    const { selectedIndex } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Mapbox.MapView
          styleURL={MAP_STYLE}
          zoomLevel={this.state.zoomLevel}
          centerCoordinate={[this.state.userPosition.longitude, 
this.state.userPosition.latitude]}
          style={styles.mapWrap}
        >
          {this.renderMap(checkpoint, "checkpoint")}
        </Mapbox.MapView>

      </View>
    );
}
setBounds = () => {
this.getMapVisibleBounds(this.map)
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  })
  .then(bounds => {
    this._setMapBounds(bounds);// set state bounds
    return this.props.onLoadQuest(bounds); //api call
  });
 }
}
```

// annotations rendering

```
class checkPoint extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }



  renderAnnotations = (data, id) => {
    const uniqKey = `checkpoint_${id}`;
    return (
      <Mapbox.PointAnnotation key={uniqKey} id={uniqKey} coordinate={[data[0], data[1]]}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={idx => this.onSelect(id)}>
          <Image source={checkPointImg} style={styles.selfAvatar} resizeMode="contain" />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </Mapbox.PointAnnotation>
    );
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.props.checkpoint || isEmpty(this.props.checkpoint)) {
      return null;
    }
    const { hits } = this.props.checkpoint;
    if (!Array.isArray(hits)) {
      return [];
    }

    return hits.map((c, idx) =>
      this.renderAnnotations(c._source.location.coordinates, c._source.id)
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"PointAnnotation" is legacy, try passing your points to  as an object. You're map render will be so much faster once you make the swap. Something like this.

```
<MapboxGL.MapView
    centerCoordinate={[ userLocation.longitude, userLocation.latitude ]}
    pitchEnabled={false}
    rotateEnabled={false}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    showUserLocation={true}
    styleURL={'your_style_url'}
    userTrackingMode={MapboxGL.UserTrackingModes.MGLUserTrackingModeFollow}
    zoomLevel={10}
>

    <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
        key='icon'
        id='icon'
        onPress={this._onMarkerPress}
        shape={{type: "FeatureCollection", features: featuresObject }}
        type='geojson'
        images={images}
    >
        <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer 
            id='icon'
            style={layerStyles.icon}
        />
    </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
</MapboxGL.MapView>
```

Where "featuresObject" looks something like this...

```
        let featuresObject = []

        annotation.forEach((annot, index) => {
            let lat = annot.latitude
            let lng = annot.longitude


            featuresObject[index] = {
                type: "Feature",
                geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [lng, lat]
                },
                properties: {
                    exampleProperty: propertyValue,
                }
            }
        })
```

[Example for polygon layer](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/example/src/components/GeoJSONSource.js)

[Example with custom icon](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/example/src/components/ShapeSourceIcon.js)

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your answer. The problem aw indeed in the PointAnnotation. I ended up making a component like this

Comment: wroking great now. Though the annotation disapears on zoom in

Comment: That's really strange, I haven't  any issues on zoom. What kind of annotation do you have? Custom icon? Polygon?

Comment: yes, it's a custom icon, a png to be precise. Actually, the project I'm working on, is a treasure hunt game where we display player icon, chests on a map

Comment: the problem seems to be related to he fact that on zoom,  a request is sent to the server to fetch the annotations to be displayed. For some reason, on zoom in, though, we get some annotation, none are displayed

Comment: but It works on zoom out. very weird. And also, the map seems o crash in dev mode on Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can add markers dynamically by using this code:

Create marker component:

```
const Marker = ({ coordinate, image, id }) => {
    return (
      <MapboxGL.MarkerView coordinate={coordinate} id={id}>
      // Add any image or icon or view for marker
        <Image
            source={{ uri: image }}
            style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
      </MapboxGL.MarkerView>
    );
 };
```

Consume it inside MapBoxGL:

```
<MapboxGL.MapView
      style={{
        // it will help you keep markers inside mapview
        overflow: 'hidden'
      }}>
{markers &&
      markers?.length > 0 &&
         markers.map((marker, index) => (
            <Marker
              coordinate={[marker.longitude, marker.latitude]}
              // id must be a string
              id={`index + 1`}
              image={getIconUrl(index)}
            />
         ))
}
</MapboxGL.MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const layerStyles = Mapbox.StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    iconImage: "{icon}",
    iconAllowOverlap: true,
    iconSize: 0.5,
    iconIgnorePlacement: true
  }
});
const mapboxIcon = props => {
  return (
    <Mapbox.ShapeSource
      shape={makeMapBoxGeoJson(props.datum, props.mapKey, props.name)}
      key={`${props.name}_key_${props.mapKey}`}
      id={`${props.name}_${props.mapKey}`}
      images={getIcon(props.name)}
      onPress={idx => (props.isActive ? props.onSelectId(props.mapKey) : null)}
    >
      <Mapbox.SymbolLayer
        id={`${props.mapKey}_pointlayer`}
        style={[layerStyles.icon, { iconSize: props.iconSize ? props.iconSize : 0.5 }]}
      />
    </Mapbox.ShapeSource>
  );
};
```